# Slow VBA Loop - Paste from Recordset

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a loop instead of copyfromrecordset for two columns that break copyfromrecordset for some unknown reason. When I loop through this it takes over 2 minutes to do 800 rows which seem extremely slow. Copyfromrecordset can enter 800 rows with 10 times as many columns in less than 20 seconds. Can anyone tell what is making the loop so slow?

```
Set rng = Activesheet.Range("P2")
Row = 0
Do While Not Rs1.EOF
    For col = 0 To Rs1.Fields.Count - 1
            rng.Offset(Row, col).Value = Rs1(col)
    Next col
    Row = Row + 1
    Rs1.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: It's slow because it is accessing each individual field in the recordset, and it is updating the worksheet for each individual field.  (`CopyFromRecordset` just transfers the whole recordset to the worksheet in a single transfer step.)

Comment: Were you using a single cell address when you tried `CopyFromRecordset`?  `CopyFromRecordset` works best when the range refers to the to lop left cell, regardless of the size of the Recordset. If `CopyFromRecordset` is causing you problems, you might consider the `GetRows` function which will return the data as an array, you'd then need to transpose the array and insert the *entire* array in one step.

Comment: I am a big fan of this suggestion ^^^^^^^

Comment: @thunderframe I was using a single cells for copyfromrecordset. All columns worked except the two I am trying to paste through the loop. The get rows array will need a dynamic range as opposed to the Copyfromrecordset, correct?

Comment: yes, you'll need to refer to a range with the same dimensions as the transposed array. The transposition is the painful part, for some reason the GetRows function returns the array indexed by column *then* row, instead of Excel's default of Row *then* Column. You can cheat and use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` but it won't work once your recordset has more than 16384 records, as that would exceed the number of columns in modern versions of Excel. You might also need to check that the array returned by GetRows is 1-based or 0-based, otherwise you'll end up with an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ThunderFrame I was able to solve my problem. As @YowE3k said, my query was doing things one at a time. So I change the code to use .getrows.

```
 'Pasting data Headings then Values
     ArrRs1 = Rs1.GetRows
     For intColIndex = 0 To Rs1.Fields.Count - 1
        Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = Rs1.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    Dim PasteArray As Variant

    ReDim PasteArray(1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2), 0 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2)
        For j = 0 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1)
            PasteArray(i, j) = ArrRs1(j, i)
        Next
    Next

'This is pasting the data
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(PasteArray, 1) + 1, UBound(PasteArray, 2) + 1) = PasteArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with copyfromrecordset; however, if there is screenupdating happening with each row, you could turn it off and likely see some improvement in speed.  This has helped me with 'Do Until' / 'Loop', previously.

I also will turn off calculations, especially in a huge spreadsheet with lots of formulas.  Recalculations of the workbook can really slow things down, if there are spots in your code where Excel automatically updates the calculations.

```
application.screenupdating = false
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'your code'

application.screenupdating = true
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```